# Django sub queries

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a basic database that I want to pull out sub data (related) in the same view:

models.py:

```
class InvoiceHeader(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    number = models.IntegerField(unique = True)

class InvoiceLine(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    invoiceheader = models.ForeignKey(InvoiceHeader)
```

views.py:

```
def list_invoices(request):
    invoices = InvoiceHeader.objects.all()
```

What I am trying to get is the invoice total in the list_invoices view which would consist of the invoicelines.price (totalled) for each invoiceheader such that in the template I can just put:

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    {{ invoice.subtotal }}
{% endfor %}
```

I think it is something to do with def something in the models.py file but I am getting lost with this.

So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def list_invoices(request):
    invoices = Item.objects.all().annotate(subtotal=Sum('invoiceline__price'))
```

Comment: Thanks for that it works a treat.
Can I just add one more issue into the melting pot:
If I have another field in the invoiceline class called qty, then can I use that same method to perform multiple calculations like subtotal = SUM(qty*price) ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You'll need to do it in SQL, perhaps with the `extra` method.

Comment: I remember something about putting a def statement in the models.py files before which allows you to define a callable like get_invoice_total(request): subtotal = self.invoiceline.price * self.invoiceline.qty return subtotal

Comment: Sure, you could do that (although the argument would be `self` not `request`). But then you would lose the benefit of the annotate command, which is that the database does it all in one hit.

Comment: Excellent thanks for that help. It has given me everything I needed to get going now.